# Find if a line of 1 within a matrix is interrupted or not

Tags: algorithm, opencv, matrix, line

I need to understand if a **oblique line** of all one within a matrix is interrupted or not. I will give you two examples of a continuous and interrupted line.The matrix is captured via **opencv** in a line following video, therefore the position of the line within the matrix may change.
Thanks in advance

[image: Oblique continuos line]
[image: Interrupted line]

This is the image captured
[image: continuos line IMAGE]
[image: Interrupted line IMAGE]

Comment: What's an _"oblique line"_?

Comment: @Miki I changed the images. Now it should be clearer.

Comment: If you are using opencv, I would suggest you to convert all the 1s to 255, then write the matrix ( numpy array ) as an image, and replace the above screenshots with such images. This will give us a better idea of what you are looking for.

Comment: @GaneshTata ok, I added the captured images !